# Serilog LogEvent results in "{State:l}"?

Tags: c#, serilog

I've written a custom sink that writes to MySQL for an ASP.NET app.

A lot of the messages are appearing as "{State:l}", is this some bug or system log? Am I parsing the actual output incorrectly?

Here is my custom sink:

```
public async void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
{
    // logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text
}
```

I am setting up Serilog the default way.